# Tokyocabinet fatal error C1083 : cannot open include file:tcbdb.h

Tags: python, tokyo-cabinet, imposm

I am using Anaconda python (2.7). I need to install tokyocabinet (along with other dependencies) in order to install imposm.parser. But whenever I try to install it (by using pip) I get this :

```
fatal error  C1083 : cannot open include file: 'tcbdb.h' :No such file or directory.
MS visual studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe failed with exit status 2.
```

In case it matters, I am running Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit.

Package link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tokyocabinet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) This is a first time question review and it looks good to me. No idea why it was downvoted. You gave an error message. You might detail the steps you have done if you dont get an answer.

Comment: Thank you eckes.:)  I thought about writing more information but couldn't think of anything more relevant to add right now as I am a newbie to both python and stack exchange. I am hoping for someone to add anything so that i could reply with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, and I found that I needed to get the tokyo cabinet libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libtokyocabinet-dev
```

After that,

```
pip install pytc
```

worked just fine.

Comment: did you read the OP? He said he's on windows, what does ubuntu have to do with it at all?